# In a Laravel component, how to do I remove a default class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-components

In a Laravel component, you can specify default classes and merge them with extra classes that get passed in, something like this:

```
<a {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'text-white']) }}>{{ $slot }}</a>
```

But what if I want to remove that "text-white" class?  How can I pass in a list of classes to exclude from the component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditionally merge classes. You can accomplish this via the `class` method, which accepts an array of classes where the array key contains the class or classes you wish to add, while the value is a boolean expression.

```
<a {{ $attributes->class(['text-white' => $isTextWhite]) }}>{{ $slot }}</a>
```